# Kaa SDK API for C#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, iot, kaa

Is there a Kaa SDK for C# out-there?
The kaaproject.com don't seem to support C#(.Net, but maybe there is someone alternative that allows me to build something in .Net that can behave like a device (kaa endpoint); Meaning  sending messages (kaa data collections) and received messages (kaa configuration)?

Reading about the Kaa REST api, it don't seem to support sending/receiving messages. its more for administration.

Or maybe there is some other way that can be used to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Kaa platform supports the following programming languages:

- C
- C++
- Objective-C
- Java

Please see [this](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/) link for more information.